# Check whether an Excel Range represents entire row or column

Tags: excel, vba, range

I need to determine if a given Range object is actully an entire column OR entire row OR none of two.

What I do now is based on the next code which works for me.

```
If Range.Rows.Count = Range.EntireColumn.Rows.Count Then
...
ElseIf Range.Columns.Count = Range.EntireRow.Columns.Count Then
...
End If
```

I'd like to know if there's more efficient and/or elegant way of doing the same? Perhaps, some built-in property that I've overlooked?

UPD: I get the range from:

```
Worksheet.Range("NamedRange")
```

Thanks.

Comment: What you are doing is the best way, imo.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: no built-in property that I know of, but I would save the max rows and columns in `Long` variables `maxRows = Rows.Count`

Comment: It might depend on the method that is used to get the range, if you can share that detail. Another micro-optimization can be to check if the Range`.Row` is 1

Comment: Thanks, @Slai. I've updated my question to show this.

Comment: Do you mean to check for only a *single* column/row?  Your existing code wouldn't distinguish that from multiple whole rows/columns.

Comment: Thanks, @TimWilliams. This is not an issue. I can count how many there are later if I need. For now it's only type: row, col or neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I think the OP's own question contains a great answer (for most uses) and three years later no one has posted it, here it is.  I converted the same logic into these two functions:

```
Function IsEntireRow(ByVal Target As Excel.Range) As Boolean
    IsEntireRow = Target.Columns.Count = Target.EntireRow.Columns.Count
End Function

Function IsEntireColumn(ByVal Target As Excel.Range) As Boolean
    IsEntireColumn = Target.Rows.Count = Target.EntireColumn.Rows.Count
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work in all Excel versions:

```
Function cellsInRange(rng As Range) As Boolean

    Dim cellsInCol As Long, cellsInRow As Long, cols As Long, count As Long, rws As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        cellsInCol = .Columns("A").Cells.count
        cellsInRow = .Rows(1).Cells.count
    End With

    With rng
        cols = .Columns.count
        count = .Cells.count
        rws = .Rows.count
    End With

    If cols = 1 And count = cellsInCol Then
        cellsInRange = True
    ElseIf rws = 1 And count = cellsInRow Then
        cellsInRange = True
    End If

End Function
```

**Edit**

If more specific details are required about the range object, the following adaptation may prove useful:

```
Function cellsInRange(rng As Range) As String

    Dim cellsInCol As Long, cellsInRow As Long, cols As Long, count As Long, rws As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        cellsInCol = .Columns("A").Cells.count
        cellsInRow = .Rows(1).Cells.count
    End With

    With rng
        cols = .Columns.count
        count = .Cells.count
        rws = .Rows.count
    End With

    If cols = 1 And count = cellsInCol Then
        cellsInRange = "Single column"
    ElseIf rws = 1 And count = cellsInRow Then
        cellsInRange = "Single row"
    Else
        cellsInRange = "Neither single column nor single row"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I imagine this has to be adapted a little bit to distinguish entire row and entire col. As of now it is just True if any.

Comment: In that case, just change the function to return a string instead of a boolean and insert appropriate response texts in the conditional statements. The logic is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this:

```
Sub somethinglikethis()

    Dim rRange As Range

    Set rRange = Range("A:A")

    With rRange
        If .Rows.Count = 1048576 And .Columns.Count < 16384 Then
            Debug.Print "Range represents Column(s)"
        ElseIf .Rows.Count < 1048576 And .Columns.Count = 16384 Then
            Debug.Print "Range represents row(s)"
        ElseIf .Rows.Count = 1048576 And .Columns.Count = 16384 Then
            Debug.Print "Range represents whole sheet"
        Else
            Debug.Print "Range represents none of row(s) or column(s)"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

the amount of rows and columns are constants in excel (depending on Excel version):
[image]

so, you just need to count the rows and columns in the range and compare these values with default values of rows and columns

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this would be an ideal solution for me if I'd keep the file for my own use. As I plan to distribute it to a number of users with different Excel versions I am too lazy to check their versions in the code. Will keep this as a backup though.

Comment: @hypers it's is not a big deal to check the version and assign variables for next comparing, just one row of code (`if application.Version > ...` or just a `if [A:A].rows.count then = ...`) will give you the way, but of course, it is on your own...

Comment: @hypers the number depends on the file type, not on the Excel version. It can even change in the same method if the workbook is saved to a newer or older format.

Comment: @Slai it's not a big deal also to check the file type, my answer is not a solution, it's just one of the possible directions... just my thoughts... I've never faced with such kind of tasks (define what the range is column or row) and I also can't imagine where such kind of tasks can be required... asume that such kind of things is redundancy code, but again, this is just thoughts...

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to parse `rng.Address(0,0)`; in English *(rather than VBA)*:

```
s = rng.Address(0,0)
If s contains no letters then rng contains only full rows
If s contains no numbers then rng contains only full columns
```

Comment: Thanks for your pseudo-code. Initially I was thinking in same direction. But then I decided I was better off without Regexp or other string manipulation for this task.

Comment: @hypers  My post was just food for thought

Answer (score 1):

my 0,02 cents

```
Select Case rng.Address
    Case rng(1).EntireColumn.Address
        MsgBox "column"
    Case rng(1).EntireRow.Address
        MsgBox "row"
End Select
```

where `rng` is a variable of `Range` type

Comment: Thanks for your version. It seems to be not bad. However, it is a bit slower than my initial approach. A quick test (at my PC) showed that my version took about 4,96s (for 1mio iterations), while yours took near 8,33s.